# Cauchy's Residue Theorem multiple choice question.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Consider the real integral $I=\int^{\infty}_{- \infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx$. This can be computed using Cauchy's Residue Theorem. Which one of the following is false?

A)  Let $γ(R)$ be a semicircle of radius $R > 1$ traced anticlockwise, centred at the origin and closed in the lower half of the complex plane. Then $I= \lim_{R \to \infty} \oint_{γ(R)} \frac{1}{1+z^2}dz$.

B) Let $γ(R)$ be a semicircle of radius $R > 1$ traced clockwise, centred at the origin and closed in the lower half of the complex plane. Then $I= \lim_{R \to \infty} \oint_{γ(R)} \frac{1}{1+z^2}dz$.

C) $I= 2 \pi i \ \text{Res}(\frac{1}{1+z^2}, z=i)$.

D) $I= -2 \pi i \ \text{Res}(\frac{1}{1+z^2}, z=-i)$.

E) None of the above.

My answer is E), so I am saying that none of the above are false, is this correct? I have this answer because both C and D give me the right result, then A is correct according to my lecture notes. I guess the only one that I am doubting is B.

Comment: My read is A, C and D are true.  B is false. But that means no single answer out of A to E is correct. Could it be you misquoted the question?

Comment: @WADon In A, the part of the contour along the real axis goes in the wrong direction.

Comment: You are right, A is false.  I think it is not the direction that is the issue but that the two paths are either side of a pole so will not not be equal.

Comment: Yes, I misquoted the question - it's which one of the statements is false

Comment: So, are you sayinng that both A and B are false then?